# Вывод времени

Tags: время, php

Подскажите как вывести текущее время,такой код выводит время но почему то на час раньше

```
 echo date('d-m-Y H:i');
```

Comment: А время какое в PHP? Точнее часовой пояс.

Может он просто не состыкуется с вашим, поэтому и показывает разницу?

Т.е. либо в php.ini укажите timezone, либо в самом php-скрипте это сделайте: [ссылка](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А если установить пояс по умолчанию? [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Спасибо помогло!!

Answer (score 3):

У меня такая проблема была потому, что комп не хотел переключатся на зимнее время. То есть, он игнорировал новый закон Медведева ))) И потому время было на час позже, потом настроил на обновление с временных серверов - все норм.